# Can I allow report users to enter information?

Tags: reporting-services

I am making reports for the ERP system my company uses. For example this is a bill of lading report. Sometimes information is not correct, or missing, or simply just has to be entered manually (we are switching from a manual system to a more automatic one). Is there a way to make it so that parts of the ran report (so NOT in report builder) can be overwritten and/or filled in manually. I can find nothing online that talks about this.

For example, the stuff in the yellow box isent always going to be in the system and will need to be manually typed.

[I had to redact company information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJzKM.png)

I have reasearched and looked around on report builder and cant find anything. At most they talk about parameters, which is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only produce a single report at a time then parameters **are** probably what you want.

Let's say in your dataset the carrier was "Bob's Logistics".

Then you can add a parameter (say 'pCarrier') and set the default to whatever is in the database by creating a dataset (`dsCarrier`) with the query something like

```
SELECT CarrierName FROM myTable WHERE OrderID = @OrderID
```

In the report, set the textbox value expression to

```
=Parameters!pCarier.Value
```

When the report is produced, it will use the parameter value which by default is the same value as in the database/dataset. The user can overtype this in the parameter field and then hit view report again and the report will again use the parameter value but now it's whatever the user typed in.

Comment: I am working with stored procedures and I think that is affecting the ability for this to work. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: If you cannot write your own queries or stored procs  then your options will be limited. You could do what I suggested above but don't create the `dsCarrier` dataset and don't set the parameter defaults. The problem is that the user will always have to fill in the parameter values, it will never be automated.

Comment: Okay thank you, I appreciate the information.